# iphone using MPMoviePlayerController in 2 views

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm creating a navigation controller based application.
In first view, there's a button. When clicked app will play a movie for 10 seconds.
In next view, there's another button. When clicked it will also play a movie.
I'm using two different objects of MPMoviePlayerController in two views.
But my problem is that the movie is playing in first view and not in second view. The code that I used to play is same in both the views.

What might be the problem?

Comment: I'm able to fix the problem but i'm not seeing view. I fixed the problem by removing initialpaytim=-1.0
Now, I'm not seeing video. When I touch the screen, i'm seeing mediaplayer controls (buttons) in portrait mode....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your videos different? Are they both supported formats? MPMoviePlayerController is very picky over what formats it will play (.mov, .mp4, .mpv, and .3gp) and how they're encoded. Try playing the same video file in both views.

Comment: Yes, I'm using same video in both places. I'm using .3gp format which is supported on iphone.